# Binomial coefficient manipulation

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Can somebody explain why this is true? $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k}{m}\frac 1k=\sum_{k=m}^n \binom{k}{m}\frac 1k$$ This manipulation is a part of an exercise, but I'm stuck at here.

Comment: What is $\binom{k}{m}$ for $k < m$?

Comment: That qualifies as an answer.

Comment: To elaborate on the first comment, $\binom{k}{m}$ is the amount of ways to choose $m$ from $k$ objects. In how many ways can you select $m$ from $k$ objects, if $m>k$? (If it is not clear, try to use some concrete values for $m,k$ first).

Comment: or look at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Answer (score 2):

For $a$ and $b$ natural numbers with $a<b$, the binomial coefficient $$\binom ab =0,$$
therefore the first $m-1$ terms in your sum are zero.

This definition is compatible with the other basic properties of the binomial coefficient, so it depends on your definition of binomial coefficient whether you need to define this separately or not.